# How to provide translations to the client side in Elixir Phoenix?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, elixir, gettext, phoenix-framework

I need to translate stuff on the client side of my Elixir Phoenix application. What is the best workflow for that? I've the default `gettext` system on the server side with it's translation files. How do I make a subset of the translations available to the Javascript and what tool/lib is then best used for the translation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the gettext `.po` file. There are some tools you can use for this purpose, for example [i18next](http://i18next.com/). You can convert the `.po` file using the [i10next-gettext-coverter](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-gettext-converter), just add a task to Brunch to automatically do this for you.